# Rails/Javascript selectors won't find elements

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am in the process of installing the asset pipeline into an older rails app. I am getting some really strange results though. I can see that the page is rendering all of the css and the jquery that is in the `app/assets` directory but its having a hard time interacting with the html.

For instance if i inspect the page and in the console call `$("html").html();` to try grab all the html it returns `TypeError: Cannot call method 'html' of null` same when trying to grab any element that is being rendered? but the page is there. if i call `jQuery` it will return fine. so its not like it jQuery isnt there.

Comment: Does calling `jQuery('html').html()` work?

Comment: that does work. but how come. before asset pipeline it would work fine?

Answer (score 1):

`$` is just a shorthand way of writing `jQuery`. If the latter works but the former doesn't, then another script in your pipeline is probably conflicting with jQuery and trying to use the `$` symbol for something else.

Are you using any other plugins or libraries that might be trying to use `$`? Or have you accidentally overwritten it yourself by writing `$ = (something)` anywhere? Without more information it's hard to know where the problem is exactly.

If all else fails you can just stick to using `jQuery()` for all your calls. In your external script file you could also circumvent this by passing the jQuery object to a wrapper function, e.g.:

```
(function ($) {

    $('div').append('You can use $ here without having to worry about conflict.');

}(jQuery))
```

Comment: looks like there was a alternate lib trying to assign $. man that took me for a swing. thanks man

Comment: hey man yeah i went through the lib now and it looked like there was the prototype lib that wasnt firing before